# Seeding Enity Framwork with SimpleMembership and Entities with a Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to seed a Entity Framework database in my ContextInitializer class with SimpleMemberships and Entities. My Entities have a Foreign Key to the Users table as is shown below so I have populated my users first, then my Entites (Events) as is shown below in my ContextInitializer class.

```
protected override void Seed(CustomContext context)
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyContext", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

    seedUsers(context);
    seedEvents(context);
    /* snip */
}

private void seedUsers(CustomContext context)
{
    var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider) Roles.Provider;
    var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider) Membership.Provider;

    if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
    {
        roles.CreateRole("Admin");
    }

    if (membership.GetUser("test", false) == null)
    {
        membership.CreateUserAndAccount("test", "test");
    }

    if (!roles.GetRolesForUser("test").Contains("Admin"))
    {
        roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {"test"}, new[] {"Admin"});
    }
}

private void seedEvents(InviteeContext context)
    {
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider) Membership.Provider;

        events = new List<Event>()
        {
            new Event() { name = "Test 1", owner_id = membership.GetUserId("test")},
            new Event() { name = "Test 2", owner_id = membership.GetUserId("test")}
        };

        events.ForEach(p => context.Events.Add(p));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

---

When I create the Events as shown above I end up with the correct result `events[0].owner_id == 1` and I can see this working in the database but when I go to save it I end up with Foreign Key Violation. Inspecting the Users set in the context (shown below) I can see that it is empty `context.Users.Count() == 0`. So I suspect that either

- Users are added slightly differently
- I need to refresh my context after adding the users (not sure how to do this)
- I need to create the user as a User class as well and add it to my context

Thanks for your help in advance,

My Entities are:

Users:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Events:

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int owner_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("owner_id")]
    public virtual User owner { get; set; }
    /* Snip */
}
```

My Context looks like this:

```
public class CustomContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomContext()
        : base("name=MyContext")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    /* Snip */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard this question, the problem was a typo in the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection or the User class.

Web Security sets up a table in the Database "MyContext" called Users whereas my class creates a table called User

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyContext", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

---

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

}